# rsync options --partial and --temp-dir

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I am trying to run rsync which should keep incomplete files in given --temp-dir and also should not delete incomplete files if connection drops for some reason.

```
rsync --human-readable --archive --info=progress2 --relative --no-inc-recursive --dirs --append-verify --partial --temp-dir=.rsync_temp /path/to/myfile.tar.lz4 <dest-ip>:/data/
```

If I interrupt the command for some reason, and relaunch it then noticed that it did not use the incomplete file from previous runs.

I have large files from 2GB onwards in size. So its essential to use --partial to resume incomplete. Also its necessary that incomplete files are not visible in the destination folder, hence I use --temp-dir.

Any clue?

Comment: If you do not use --temp-dir, do you really not see incomplete file(s) in `/data/` on the remote host with `ls -A`? (I am sure they are there before the command is terminated, but are they really gone after that?)

Comment: With `--partial` there is no temp file created, but I see that a file with original name is created and its size keeps increasing, which I assume is being updated in-place.

Comment: Have you tried `--partial-dir=` instead of `--temp-dir=`?

Comment: Yes, `--partial-dir=DIR` moves incomplete file into DIR on rsync interruption. So it is not useful to keep ongoing incomplete file into a separate `--temp-dir`

Comment: Have you tried using both `--temp-dir` and `--partial-dir` then?

Comment: Yes I have tried that and it didnt work. 
As per my observation these two options are incompatible for the reason that `partial` files needs to be at the destination and not in `--temp-dir`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it by using `--no-whole-file`. So although using an SSH connection which executes `rsync --server` on the remote machine, it seems rsync sometimes disables the default delta-transfer algorithm and to my surprise¹ the algorithm is a requirement for `--partial`.

Another culprit could but a missing temporary directory on the remote machine as although `--partial-dir` automatically creates the missing directory, the `--temp-dir` option doesn't do it.

¹ In the past I thought `--partial` uses the destination file and simply appends the missing data. But now I think it uses the partial destination file to do a delta-transfer comparison first, before writing the missing data to a new temporary file to finally combine both.